# Multi-domain SSL Certificate and Windows Azure

Tags: azure, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a single .NET website that is currently running under a traditional hosting account.
I am using a multi-domain (5 domain) SSL certificate to handle domains for different regions i.e.

- https://www.mywebsite.com
- https://www.mywebsite.net
- https://www.mywebsite.de
- https://www.mywebsite.at
- https://www.mywebsite.co.uk

At a code level I detect the address and localize the site depending on the URL extension.

This has all worked perfectly for the past few years with no problem. Now I want to migrate this site to Windows Azure to allow for better performance and redundancy.

I have successful experience of setting up a site using a Wildcard SSL certficate under Azure (i.e. *.mywebsite.com) but I am keen to sound out whether the multi-domain SSL is also possible.

So my question is does Azure support this kind of certificate and setup, has anyone successfully achieved this and were there any pitfalls?

Comment: I'm facing this same issue right now. Did you manage to find an answer to this?

Comment: @UriAbramson - my requirements have changed fortunately, as I think this could be difficult to implement in Azure. I think the only way to prove out if this is possible is just to try and implement and see what happens.

Comment: I tried to configure it and suprisingly, it just worked. You have to upload some certificates to the Azure management portal and define them in the config files and you're good to go. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That is useful to know - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on my question, it was very simple to implement in the end. I  uploaded multiple certificates against my cloud service and the code then worked as before.